# How to limit values (clamp) in JSON with JQ?

Tags: python, json, jq

I have an application which writes/concatenates data into JSON, and then displays/graphs it via dygraphs.  At times, various events can cause the values to go out of range.  That range is user-subjective, so clamping that range at run-time is not the direction I am wishing to go.

I believe jq can help here - ideally I would be able to search for a field > x and if it is > x, replace it with x.  I've gone searching for jq examples and not really found anything that's making sense to me yet.

I have spent a bit of time on this but not been able to make anything do what I think it should do ... at all.  Like, I don't have bad code to show you because I've not made it do anything yet.  I sincerely hope what I am asking is narrowed down enough for someone to be able to show me, in context, so I can extend it for the larger project.

Here's a line which I would expect to be able to modify:

```
{"cols":[{"type":"datetime","id":"Time","label":"Time"},{"type":"number","id":"Room1Temp","label":"Room One Temp"},{"type":"number","id":"Room1Set","label":"Room One Set"},{"type":"string","id":"Annot1","label":"Room One Note"},{"type":"number","id":"Room2Temp","label":"Room Two Temp"},{"type":"number","id":"Room2Set","label":"Room Two Set"},{"type":"string","id":"Annot2","label":"Room Two Note"},{"type":"number","id":"Room3Temp","label":"Room Three Temp"},{"type":"number","id":"State","label":"State"},{"type":"number","id":"Room4Temp","label":"Room Four Temp"},{"type":"number","id":"Quality","label":"Quality"}],"rows":[
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019,6,4,20,31,13)"},{"v":68.01},{"v":68.0},null,{"v":62.02},{"v":55.89},null,null,{"v":4},{"v":69.0},{"v":1.052}]}]}
```

I'd want to do something like:

```
if JSONFile.Room2Set < 62
    set Room2Set = 62
```

[Here's a larger block of JSON](https://pastebin.com/16xq7wCt) which is the source of the chart shown below:

[Example Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBfMb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an invocation such as:

```
jq --arg col Room2Set --argjson mx 72  --argjson mn 62 -f clamp.jq input.json
```

where clamp.jq contains:

```
def clamp: if . > $mx then $mx elif . < $mn then $mn else . end;

(.cols | map(.id) | index($col)) as $ix
| .rows[].c[$ix].v |= clamp
```

the selected cells should be "clamped".

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I was able to get that to work for my needs with a slight change to make it inline and clamp an upper AND lower (which I neglected to ask for):  `jq --arg col 'Room2Set' --argjson mx 62 --argjson mn 60 'def clamp: if . > $mx then $mx elif . < - $mn then - $mn else . end;(.cols | map(.id) | index($col)) as $ix | .rows[].c[$ix].v |= clamp' input.json` was what worked.

Answer (score 2):

With a function `clamp` functions defined like so (in your ~/.jq file or inline):

```
def clamp_min($minInc): if . < $minInc then $minInc else . end;
def clamp_max($maxInc): if . > $maxInc then $maxInc else . end;
def clamp($minInc; $maxInc): clamp_min($minInc) | clamp_max($maxInc);
```

And with that data, you'll want to find the corresponding cells for each row and modify the value.

```
$ jq --arg col "Room2Set" --argjson max '62' '
def clamp_max($maxInc): if . > $maxInc then $maxInc else . end;
(INDEX(.cols|to_entries[]|{id:.value.id,index:.key};.id)) as $cols
  | .rows[].c[$cols[$col].index] |= (objects.v |= clamp_max($max))
' input.json
```

Comment: It might be worth demonstrating (or at least noting) that one can put function definitions directly inline as well. Making a script runnable only by users with specific dotfile content can be deeply counterproductive.

Comment: Fortunately this doesn't make this that much harder to read to inline it.

Comment: @JeffMercado thank you for taking the time to answer.  it looks to me as if the second code block is the inline version you mentioned, which is likely preferable in this case.  I get an error which I am ashamed to say I don't quite understand.
```jq: error: INDEX/2 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
def clamp_max($maxInc): if . > $maxInc then $maxInc else . end; (INDEX(.cols|to_entries[]|{id:.value.id,index:.key};.id)) as $cols | .rows[].c[$cols[$col].index] |= (objects.v |= clamp_max($max)) 
```
It sounds like the column name is wrong, but I've triple checked.

Comment: @LCB I believe it was added to version 1.6. You should be able to copy the implementation from [builtin.jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq) and it should work as long as you have 1.5 (it uses streaming).

Comment: Yes sir, that was the problem.  I'm using Debian Buster and the version I received with apt was jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe.  Thank you for the clarification.